# Fractions with different denominators

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Lets have the following fractions.

$121393/28657$

$121393/17711$

$121393/10946$

$121393/?$

What number is on the denominator of the last fraction where the question mark is?

Also, which algebraic number do these fractions represent?

Comment: I see the question has been amended after my answer was posted: it did seem uncommonly easy.

Comment: @ Weather Vane. I'm sorry. I forgot to put the second part of the question.

Comment: Does the extra question turn it into a maths problem? There are **four** fractions with different values: are you asking a question about roots of a polynomial?

Comment: The values of the fractions derive from the same algebraic number.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{1 + \sqrt5}{2}$ ?

Comment: The algebraic  number you give is the correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is

> $6765$
>
>  The third denominator is the difference between the first two denominators:
>  $28657 - 17711 = 10946$
>
>  So I subtracted the third denominator from the second:
>  $17711 - 10946 = 6765$
>
>  The numerator does not seem to have any role.
>  It is always the same, and there are no common factors.
>  There seems to be a simple series, with a red herring.

Comment: rot13(Fb gur snpg gur sbhe ahzoref juvpu nccrne ner nyy Svobanppv ahzoref (S21=10946, S22=17711, S23=28657, S26=121393) vf n pbvapvqrapr be erq ureevat?)

Comment: It may be important that the denominators are in the golden ratio, accurate to more than 8 decimal places.

Comment: @eru-cs that makes it neat, but evidently wasn't needed to find the solution.